# Output Impedance of a Pre-amplifier

Tags: bjt, preamp

This is an AC equivalent circuit of a pre-amplifier. I already derived the formula for input impedance (Zi) but I'm having trouble getting the formula for output impedance (Zo). I can't find a way to incorporate R3 into the formula. Also how do I derive the formula for Vi and Vo?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKKi85.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject a 1mA current to output pin, with input pin having NO connection or being shorted to GND.

Now, for your chosen condition, compute the output voltage given the 1mA current.

Comment: RE: "with input pin having NO connection or being shorted to GND" only one of these options is correct in general (i.e. for finding the Z22 of any 2-port).

Comment: How about the output impedance?

Comment: I don't really get it. Can you kindly explain further?

Comment: Expand your small-signal model by ONE component: a 1mA current source. Then write the equations, or run a sim, to discover the Vout. Divide Vout by 1mA, and that is your answer.